# Magento Certified Developer Plus: are EE questions eliminatory?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-enterprise, magento-1, certification, ee-1.14

I'm planning to book my Developer Plus certification this year.

However, I haven't worked a lot with EE.

I already got my Developer certification and I was wondering if **the EE questions in the Developer Plus exam are eliminatory ?**

For instance, **if I get the questions from the Developer exam right and all the EE questions wrong, will I still pass ?**

Comment: I've already provided some details on this here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/119876/1956

Comment: @ryanF awesome thanks for the details you got my upvote

Comment: Glad it's helps (thanks for the up-vote)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As far as I know my answer is `no` .

Below is the passing criteria for each certification exam :

> Magento Certified Developer exam: 37 or higher
>
> Magento Certified Developer Plus exam: **For sections 11 & 12 combined a score of 7 or higher** AND meet the overall passing score of 48 or higher
>
> Magento Certified Front End Developer exam: 44 or higher
>
> Magento Certified Solution Specialist exam: 39 or higher

In Developer plus exam section 11 and 12 purely ask for **EE** so you have to score  at least 7 in combine in those two section so yes **EE questions are eliminatory**

As far as I know There is 15 additional question asked in 11 & 12 section for **developer plus** exam, so you have to make 7 Right out of that 15 , rest of the sections remains same as **Developer exam**

Source : https://magento-u-support.magento.com/hc/en-us/sections/360001850452-Frequently-Asked-Questions

Comment: Can you please suggest any Links or Documents , how to pass Magento Certification Exam? # Murtuza Zabuawala

Comment: Great thanks for that I couldn't find the info, link is helpful =)

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism You are always Welcome Bro :)

Comment: I even failed the first time with a sufficient overall passing score but only a score of 6 for sections 11 & 12 :o

Comment: @7ochem you are the first who tell me that you failed in 11 & 12 section  otherwise all of my friends pass or fail all over exam in developer plus

Comment: Yes, it's a shame. But I got it the second time ;)

Comment: @7ochem its not shame , its your bad time you failed for just 1